# Two column layout with left fluid and right fill the rest width

Tags: html, css

I need something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483969/horizontal-list-of-2-items-with-second-fixed-width-and-first-fill-width) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width). However I want the right column not to be fixed size, but variable size. Is it possible?

```
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
|some text|stretch to fill the remaining space        | <- viewport
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/2333/
Fiddle from link I posted.
right does not need fixed width. See link above

```
width:auto
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

This is the `float` solution. You can set a fixed `width` to `.one` column, or leave as it is to let the content to decide. And set `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: hidden;` to `.two` column.

```css
.one {
    float: left;
    background: aqua;
}
.two {
    overflow: auto;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">hello</div>
<div class="two">world</div>
```

The `flexbox` solution. The key is to set `flex: 1;` aka `flex-grow: 1;` to the dynamic width column. Follow [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) to see the browser support tables.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
}
.one {
    background: aqua;
}
.two {
    flex: 1;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">hello</div>
<div class="two">world</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  missing something but couldn't this be used for each item?

```
<div>
<span>left text<span/><span>right text<span/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If a two-column-ish button is what you are after... (your ascii screenshot looks like this), so: diving the space in the best way but with one side winning, if it gets tight ➝ no truncated price, but truncated label if it has to be... ➪ [full source on codepen](http://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/ZOaRpN?editors=1100)

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="two">125&thinsp;€</div>
    <div class="one">my favorite provider</div>
</div>
```

CSS (stylus)

```
.container
    clearfix()
    border 2px solid purple

.one, .two
    padding 4px

.two
    background #aca 
    float right
    white-space nowrap
    text-overflow ellipsis

.one
    background #caa 
    overflow hidden 
    white-space nowrap
    text-overflow ellipsis
```